# Multiple HTML5 selects share one list

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have 10 fields in the form, all of which need to be a select that goes from the year 1950 to the year 2017. Is it possible to create one list from 1950 to 2017 and let each of the selects reference that list? Or would I have to create 10 identical lists, each for each select.

Edit: An obvious application would be birthdate of all family members? (isn't the need for multiple identical selects extremely obvious?)

Edit 2: I thought there would be functionality similar to how you can write one datalist and have lots of inputs reference that datalist. Is this not a legitimate question? lol

Comment: If they all need to reference the year selected .. Why not have a single select?  I really don't understand the need for 10 selects if they are all to have the same info . .

Comment: An obvious application would be birthdate of all family members? (isn't the need for multiple identical selects extremely obvious?)

Comment: You should really use `<input type='number' min='1950' max='2017'>` for years. Or `<input type='date'>`

Comment: For forms with an arbitrary number of copies of itself, you should consider using a template. You will have to create only one list and duplicate it via javascript. If you want, I can elaborate...

Comment: `extremely obvious` Says the person not asking a **thorough** question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Each select needs it's own `<option>`s . But you can copy one set 10 times

Comment: I don't see this as a smart solution at all but if have no other choices i can help you with a javascript code in which you can create as much as you need select (even more than 10 ) with any dates you want (from 0 to 2017) !

Comment: Thanks guys! I can write my own code to duplicate the list. I just thought that there might be a more elegant solution similar to the ability to share datalists. Maybe you guys are more experience coders than me, but I thought this was a legitimate question. @Zak you've contributed nothing to this thread at all...

Comment: `<select>` is still not a numeric input though.

Comment: Essentially, what I need is the year scroller on the facebook sign up page, but x 10 or so. I tried input number before, but it doesn't look and function as aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to reuse the same list on multiple elements, or create custom component, but they are all over-complicated compared to just copying the element, or its HTML:

```js
// add 1 clone with different attribute
var sel2 = sel1.cloneNode(true)
sel2.id = 'sel2'
sel1.parentNode.appendChild(sel2)  // or sel.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', sel2)

// insert 9 clones, but with the same atributes 
sel1.outerHTML += Array(10).join(sel1.outerHTML)
```

```html
<select id=sel1>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```